# ¿Por qué cuando ejecuto la app en Android Studio me instala la app en el teléfono pero no se ve el icono launcher en la pantalla?

Tags: android, android-studio

Pasa que ejecuto mi app en Android Studio sin problemas, me instala la aplicación en el teléfono y funciona sin problemas. Sin embargo el icono launcher de la aplicación no se ve en la pantalla del teléfono, no está en ningún lado, pero cuando voy a ver las aplicaciones instaladas en el teléfono si está instalada, sólo que no se ve el launcher...

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Este es mi manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="apps.tonum.tonum">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    //para google maps
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:label="Tonum"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Matías, Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml, recuerda agregar más información .

Comment: @Jorgesys arriba agregué el manifest, se me había olvidado dar esa información. Gracias!

Comment: Gracias a tí Matías, de esta forma te pueden dar mejores y mas acertadas respuestas, al principio imagine que podía faltar <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> pero al ver tu Manifest.xml veo que es otra la causa, agregué una respuesta por cierto :)

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estas definiendo como icono de tu aplicación:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
```

el problema se puede deber a :

- En alguno de los directorios `/mipmap` correspondientes a la densidad de tu dispositivo no se encuentra la imagen. Revisa que todos contengan la imagen.
- el recurso `@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground` no es una imagen o es una transparencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué raro, los tengo en todos esos... Será porque todas las imágenes son png?